# Unable to mount from a script using shebang (kernel hardening related ?)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel, mount, shebang

I stumbled across a really weird issue with `mount`. I'm unable to make sense out of it.

For some context, I wrote a Python script that aims to automount hot-pluggable USB devices, but this is not relevant.

Here's the mount error that occurs:

```
mount: /media/usb/backup: filesystem was mounted, but any subsequent operation failed: Operation not permitted.
```

I have a LUKS partition already unlocked and I'm trying to mount it using my script.

```
$ lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME                                     MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sdb                                        8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1                                     8:17   0   64M  0 part
├─sdb2                                     8:18   0  128M  0 part
├─sdb3                                     8:19   0   10G  0 part
└─sdb4                                     8:20   0  1.8T  0 part
  └─cfe1c7ab-36cc-4419-9373-764aaae1033f 254:1    0  1.8T  0 crypt
```

I created a minimal reproducible example which is as follow:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
mount /dev/mapper/cfe1c7ab-36cc-4419-9373-764aaae1033f
```

The `x` bit is set and when I run this script using the shebang, I get the same error as above:

```
$ sudo /tmp/test
mount: /media/usb/backup: filesystem was mounted, but any subsequent operation failed: Operation not permitted.
```

The weird thing is that if I run this exact same command in my shell, it does work:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/cfe1c7ab-36cc-4419-9373-764aaae1033f
$ echo $?
0
```

When I run my script not using the shebang but by using the bash explicitly, it works as well:

```
$ sudo bash /tmp/test
$ echo $?
0
```

So apparently there's something happening with the shebang which triggers the `Operation not permitted` error. If I'm not mistaken the shebang is handled directly by the kernel, therefore I'm starting to wonder if it has anything to do with the fact I'm using ArchLinux's [`linux-hardened`](https://github.com/anthraxx/linux-hardened) (which is a fork of GraphenOS kernel).

Are you aware of any Linux mechanism (mount namespace?) that could trigger that error when running a script with a shebang ? Thanks for reading me.

Comment: What happens if you edit the `/tmp/test` script to use the same command you type on the command line?  I.e., `sudo mount /dev/mapper/....`

Comment: Huh, nice catch... It works. I feel embarrassed now for not trying this myself :-) Thanks! Though I'd be glad to have an explanation as to what's going on here